# The Image Size Issue Coming From Server In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am working on application in which the images are coming from server which i have to display  in `UIImageview` which size is of screen size. the problem is some image resolution are very bigger. So, when I use **AspectFill** it does not appear properly, it is getting shrink and when I use **AspectFit** it appears in rectangle shape in image view . so is there any way to display image in `UIImageView` without getting shrink and without getting croped.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't think so is there a way but for image you should aspect fit only.

Answer (score 1):

I think changing contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill of your imageView should help:

```
yourImageView.image = yourImage;
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

CGRect frame = someImageView.frame;
frame.size = yourImage.size;
yourImageView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image imageSize:(CGSize)size
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        //here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage;

    }
```

And then use new image for your `imageView`

You can set image using

```
UIImage * image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
CGSize size=CGSizeMake(50, 63);//set the width and height 
UIImage resizedImage= [self resizeImage:image imageSize:size];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
UIImageView  *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
yourImageView.image = yourImage;
```

i hope it helps.